# Working with Collections and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, equals

I got a problem, where I cant get the value out of an HashMap but I am sure, the key i want to get the value out with, is in the map (but not the same instance).
So here is, what i have:
I got a HiberKey, and a HiberVal.

```
public class HiberKey {
    private int id;
}

public class HiberVal {
  private int id;
}
```

And while the programm is running, it does a transaction now and then, and at some point i got a Hashmap AND a single HiberKey single_key. The problem here is, that i wanted to execute map.get(single_key) i allways get a null value, but im shure, there is the same value in the map (not same reference, but also of an transaction from the hibernate-session).
The first thing i thought of was equals & hashcode, but those methodes are already implemented in HiberKey.

A solution would be to fill the map with key.id instead of hiberkey and call map.get(single_key.id), but thats not the idea of hibernate i think, and i got quite more complicated sctructures with Hashmaps in maps and so on, and if i fill all of them with integer, its not really handy and readable any more

Does anyone have a suggestion, why this could occour?
Thanks for any advice.

Hibernateversion: 3.5.3

```
@Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof BabelKey)) {
      return false;
    }
    return ((BabelKey) obj).id == id;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return String.valueOf(id).hashCode();
  }
```

**// UPDATE:**

Ok, here is an example where i iterate the map with additional out.println debugging, and in the output you can see the key is in the map, but simply does not work. 
output:

```
--------------------------
Following keys in Map:
Keys with no null value: 301 //Key is In Map
Keys with no null value: 304
Keys with no null value: 303
Keys with no null value: 307
Searched key: 301 //same key
Result: null //result is null
Next Try: null
```

**// UPDATE2:**

I compared the two key files, and equals returns true, and they also have the same hashcode. But somehow Hibernate uses Javaassist, so different instances wont work out with a HashMap. I think the only solution for that, is to save the id in the hashmap and compare the id of them.

Comment: I'm trying to follow what you are saying, but its a bit difficult.  Are you saying you are using an object as the key within a HashMap, but when you try to retrieve a value from the HashMap using a key that should equal one of the present keys in the HashMap, it returns null?  Can we see then entirety of the entities you are using and also the code that references the HashMap?

Comment: yes thats what i wanted to say. im sorry that i cant provide full code, because of company-law :(

Comment: Are you instantiating new instances of the key when you add them to the HashMap?  Can I see the code you are running your test with?

Answer (score 0):

In order to utilize an Object properly as a key to a HashMap, you must override the hashCode() and equals() methods properly for it to work.  You must guarantee that those methods will give the same results with different instances of an object that contains the same data in order for it to work properly.

You must also verify that the object you are using as a key does not change in any way that would make the hashCode() method give different result prior to retrieving from the HashMap.

I recommend that the object that you are using as a key be immutable.

EDIT: I am adding a link that explains the problems and solutions to issues you may incur while using an Object as a key. There are a lot.  I suggest that you walk through this article.

http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Comment: equals and hascode were already implemented by. (implementation added in question)

Comment: If you are using a primitive int as the id, why not just return the id for hashCode()?

Comment: Does maybe HashMap not call hashCode() but calls a HashMap specific hashmethode?

Comment: no, it calls equals() then hashCode().  Make the id field final and see if that helps.  That will prevent the value from possibly changing.

Comment: i compared the two key objects with consoleoutput of equals and hashcode, and it gives me true and the same hashcode. But the Answer for this problem is:
There is no solution. Hibernate uses Javassist, which manipulates your java classes and also manipulate your hashcode and equals methodes. The Problem is, that i have two different instances of the same object. Does not work out.

Comment: That's not the way Hibernate works.  It may use Javaassist, but it never subverts such core functionality.  We need more code - can you : Take a  copy of both your Entity and Key classes, rename them to something bland, then strip out everything except the key and id properties and the equals&hashcode methods.  That should satisfy company law, and give us enough to work with.